# How would I go about keeping a reference to a location before NSAttributedString conversion so that it's still valid after?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsattributedstring

I have a plain text string that I'm running through a parser (in this case DTCoreText) to get out an NSAttributedString.

How would I best go about remembering an index in the string before conversion, so it's still valid after conversion (so say I could insert a new string at that index)? The parsing over the plain text into NSAttributedString obviously removes things which makes it difficult to keep track.

Comment: Is the index you talking about known before parsing or you get to know it during the parsing process? If it's initialized before parsing, and there is only one value to keep track of, it's used during app runtime, just keep it as instance variable or property. If there are many of them you'd better use dictionary to store the desired values, and keep that dictionary. If you have to persist the index (indexes?) then you can keep them in `NSUserDefaults` or, even store to file. Another option could be keeping the whole original string, and search it for the index you are talking about each time.

Comment: It's known before parsing, but my issue is that after parsing (which is effectively a black box) it's no longer necessarily valid. It may have been at index 21 before then 14 after parsing for instance.

Comment: Your question is somewhat confusing. Can you please edit it with examples? I mean, your original string, result string, and what you are looking for in those strings?

Comment: Doug, what is it that you are trying to do with this conversion. I'm asking because DTCoreText doesn't do anything that someone else can't do very very very very very easily just using the stuff Apple gives us, if you tell me what it is you are converting or how you need it to look, I can give you the attributed string code in about 5-10 minutes, it's not so hard that you need to use a thrid party library.